# Rails 3: my jquery for drop menu not working, causing other js to not work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to jquery but I'm trying to learn. I'm working with a drop down button that works just fine in jsfiddle. However, when I try it in my rails 3 app, it won't work. (nothing drops down when you click the link).

If I remove the line $(".menu").fixedMenu(); and add it into the html like this it works. I'm stumped as to why its not working like the jsfiddle example

```
<script>
        $('document').ready(function(){
            $('.menu').fixedMenu();
        });
        </script>
```

Would really appreciate any help or insights.

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rKaPN/32/

application.js

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.fixedMenu = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
      var menu = $(this);
        $("html").click(function() {
        menu.find('.drop-down').removeClass('drop-down');
      });
      menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click',function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        //check whether the particular link has a dropdown
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('single-link') && !$(this).parent().hasClass('current')) {
          //hiding drop down menu when it is clicked again
          if ($(this).parent().hasClass('drop-down')) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('drop-down');
          }
          else {
            //displaying the drop down menu
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.drop-down').removeClass('drop-down');
            $(this).parent().addClass('drop-down');
          }
        }
        else {
          //hiding the drop down menu when some other link is clicked
          $(this).parent().parent().find('.drop-down').removeClass('drop-down');

      }
      })
    });
  }
  $(".menu").fixedMenu();
  })(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $("div.post_form").hide();

    $("input[name$='post[category_id]']").click(function() {


        $("div.post_form").hide();
        $("#extra").show("slow")
    });
});

$(function(){
        $('a.tab_link').click(function(){
          $('a.tab_link').removeClass('active')
          $(this).addClass('active')
        });
      });
```

application_layout.html.erb

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title><%= title %></title>
      <%= csrf_meta_tag %> 
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'token-input-facebook' %>
      <!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]-->
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>


    </head>

    <body style="<%= check_user %>">

    <header>


    <div class="menu">
        <div class="container-margin">
        <ul>
             <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path, :class => "single_link" %><span></span></a></li>
             <li> <%= link_to "Profile", root_path, :class => "single_link" %><span></span></a></li>
             <li> <%= link_to "Blog", root_path, :class => "single_link" %><span></span></a></li>
             <li class="menu-right">
               <a href="#">More<span class="arrow"></span></a>
               <!-- Drop Down menu Items -->
                <ul>
               <li><a href="http://www.google.co.in/reader">Reader Reader Reader</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://sites.google.com">Sites</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://groups.google.co.in">Groups</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


      <div id="header-two">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="logo"><%= link_to logo, root_path %></div>
            <div id="search">
                       <%= form_tag search_posts_path, :method => :get do %>
                       <%= submit_tag "", :name => nil, :class => "search-button" %>
                       <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], :class => "search-box round-3" %>
                    <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </header>
```

custom.css

```
#header-two {
    background:#fff;
    height: 74px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ececec;   
}
.container-margin {
    width: 1034px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.menu{
position::absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif;
color:#999;
height:30px;
background:blue;
}
.menu a:hover{
background-color:#676767;
color:#CCCCCC;
}
.menu a{
text-decoration:none;
padding:6px 8px 7px;
color:#CCCCCC;
outline:none;
}
.menu ul{
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0 0 0 10px;
}
.menu ul li{
padding:0;
float:left;
}
.menu ul li.menu-right{
float:right;
}

.menu ul li ul li{
padding:0;
float:none;
margin:0 0 0 0px;
width:100%;
}
.menu ul li ul{
position:absolute;
right: 0px;
border:1px solid #C3D1EC;
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 5px #CCCCCC;
   -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 5px #CCCCCC;
        box-shadow:0 1px 5px #CCCCCC;
margin-top:-1px;
display:none;
padding:0px 16px 0px 0;
}
.drop-down ul{
display:block !important;
position:relative;
}
.drop-down a{
background-color:white;
border:1px solid #C3D1EC;
border-bottom:0;
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0 -1px 5px #CCCCCC;
   -moz-box-shadow:0 -1px 5px #CCCCCC;
        box-shadow:0 -1px 5px #CCCCCC;
display:block;
height:29px;
padding:0 8px 0 8px;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
color:#3366CC;
}
.drop-down a:hover{
background-color:white;
color:#3366CC;
}
.drop-down ul a:hover{
background-color:#e4ebf8;
}
.drop-down ul a{
border:0 !important;
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 #CCCCCC;
   -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 #CCCCCC;
        box-shadow:0 0 0 #CCCCCC;
border:0;
width:100%;
}

.arrow {
border-color:#C0C0C0 transparent white;
border-style:solid dashed dashed;
margin-left:5px;
position:relative;
top:10px;
}
.mid-line{
background-color:#FFF;
border-top:1px solid #e5e5e5;
font-size:0;
}
```

Comment: This is a plain jQuery issue - nothing to do with Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function($) {...}` is a function. `$(function($) {...})` is not. If you want it to run it when the document finishes loading you should erase the `(jQuery)` in the end (also, the `$` argument in the function's declaration is redundant in this case). If you want to run it when the script is loaded then just erase the initial `$`.

Comment: hi i tried what you said but its still not working, I had to adjust the fixedMenu() line into my html, any idea why its not working like the js fiddle example?

Comment: Can you post your exact code (the one with the change that still isn't working)?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first $

It should be "(function () {" not "$(function () {"